# java swing setXXXSize() alternative?

Tags: java, swing, layout, size, layout-manager

I always see many threads here how setting an components size using setXxxSize() method where

```
Xxx=Preferred
Xxx=Maximum
Xxx=Minimum
```

Or just     setSize ()     in general are all bad ideas but nobody suggests an alternative when we do need an element to be of an fixed size regardless of available space in the layout.
Any best practices to be followed here?

Answer (score 3):

1. **Override** `getPreferredSize()` of the `JComponent` to (first check the size suggested by the `super` method, and if not suitable) return the size required.
2. Then put the component into a layout (e.g. `FlowLayout`) or layout + constraint (e.g. `GridBagLayout` & appropriate `GridBagConstraints`) which will *honor that size* (i.e. not stretch the height or width).

See also [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)

Comment: So the idea is to define your own size and not let the layout decide for you?. But what about other layouts where you cant decide if your component will be stretched (like border layout CENTER) for example?

Comment: *"(like border layout CENTER)"* put a panel in it. Set the panel layout to either flow layout or (I'd go for) grid bag layout. Put the component in that panel. The panel will be stretched to the full width and height given to the `CENTER` constraint, but the custom component will retain its preferred size.